# Как прикрепить BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, material-design

В новой библиотеке появился Bottom navigation view. Мне надо сделать так, чтобы когда я пролистывал список вниз (например строк) он прятался, а когда пролистывал список вверх - он появлялся.

Вот как на этом видео - https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_9/0B3321sZLoP_HNUFCLXIwV2FOcDQ/components_bottomnavigation_behavior_backtotop.webm

Вот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.isAttachedToWindow();

       listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

       String[] array = new String[20];
       for(int i =0; i<20;i++)
       {
           array[i] = "item"+i;
       }
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Вот XML код -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.kerjen.exodus.learning_1.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"/>


<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorBNV"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorTextBNV"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorTextBNV"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых нужно это все разместить в CoordinatorLayout. Во-вторых для такого эффекта нужно использовать RecyclerView а не ListView. CoordinatorLayout не работает с ListView. В-третьих нужно создать кастомный Behavior